# Cross-Multiplying Queries

Tags: sql

i like to get the serial numbers which are not yet included on the Customer_Machine table. but instead, the rows are cross multiplying. this is my code.

```
SELECT serial_number.serial_no 
FROM   product 
       INNER JOIN serial_number 
               ON product.productid = serial_number.productid 
       INNER JOIN customer_machine 
               ON NOT( customer_machine.serial_no = serial_number.serial_no )
```

any help please ?

Comment: some sample data , desired output etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you join `Product` and `serial_number` tables, results will be `serial numbers which are in products but not in customer_machine`. Since above answers handle that case, this query is to  select `serial numbers which are not in customer_machine` (as you have described) using a `left join` and ignoring `Product` table.

[**Sql-Server fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a809/1)

```
select s.serial_no
from serial_number s 
    left join customer_machine c on s.serial_no = c.serial_no
where c.serial_no is null
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
SELECT serial_number.serial_no 
FROM   product P
INNER JOIN serial_number S
       ON P.productid = S.productid 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM customer_machine 
                  WHERE serial_no = S.serial_no)
```

What you are doing now, is joining with the `customer_machine` for every `serial_no` from  `serial_number` that doesn't match with the same number from `customer_machine`; so you are multiplying your results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT serial_number.serial_no 
FROM   product
       INNER JOIN serial_number 
               ON product.productid = serial_number.productid 
       LEFT JOIN customer_machine 
               ON ( customer_machine.serial_no = serial_number.serial_no)
 WHERE customer_machine.serial_no IS NULL
```

Comment: I think that you want to take the `customer_machine.serial_no IS NULL` condition from the join condition and add it on the `WHERE`, otherwise it won't filter results at all

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want to exclude the specific serial numbers that already exist, rather than joining them in.  You can do this in your where clause:

```
SELECT serial_number.serial_no 
FROM   product 
INNER JOIN serial_number 
           ON product.productid = serial_number.productid 
WHERE serial_number.serial_no NOT IN ( SELECT customer_machine.serial_no
                                       FROM customer_machine )
```